# Interviews during No-Shave November (Unkempt Beard)

Tags: professionalism, interviewing

I am currently a university student in the United States and enjoy participating in No-Shave November each year to help raise cancer awareness.

I am currently applying for post graduation jobs and have a couple of interviews lined up for this month. **When interviewing with a company where beards are allowed, how important is it that your beard be kempt?**

With my age it doesn't grow in the fullest, and looks scrappy at times. I am willing to shave if I have to, but would prefer not to if keeping it has no impact on my candidacy.

If you are interviewing someone who is competent and qualified, does unkempt facial hair still have an effect on your rating of their qualification for the position? (Not a position where I directly interact with customers or clients)

**Edit**

@DavidK linked [Chad's answer](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/a/13221/16983) from the duplicate question. There he discusses the difference between a groomed and a not groomed beard. The point made in it is that it may appear unprofessional as to them it may seem that you don't care to take the time to maintain it.

@Meelah notes that while it is for a good cause, I am implying to the interviewer that I prioritize it over my chances with the company.

I understand that this question is a duplicate as I did not read far enough down on the linked question. Thank you to all who commented, you were very helpful and answered my question.

Comment: I closed this as a duplicate as it seems to be the exact same question as currently written.

Comment: Have to disagree here.  Linked question is about a beard that is maintained.  This question is about unkempt facial hair.  World of difference.

Comment: I found that question, but it doesn't address messy beards/facial hair and its effect on how the candidate is perceived. Will try to edit the question to further distinguish the two questions.

Comment: [KeithS's answer](http://workplace.stackexchange.com/a/13222/16983) does address messy facial hair. "Beards are generally acceptable as long as they look well-groomed..."

Comment: Voting to re-open.  This is different.  As a beard wearer myself, there is a world of difference between the question of neat beard vs hipster, and having scrappy stubble for charity as a young guy looking for a job.

Comment: @DavidK Just because 2 questions can have the same answer doesn't make them the same question. I also don't think the 2 questions would even have the same answers.

Comment: I agree the question should be re-opened.  But I would strongly advise against trying to do an interview looking ungroomed.  Even if you explain it's for charity, it'll come across as a sign of immaturity, being stuck in college-age pranks and being unwilling to prioritise the job over fun, albeit fun in a good cause.  IMO it could lose you the job, so shave!

Comment: Tempted to agree with the duplicate. General consensus seems to be that unkempt facial hair could have a non-negligible ‎detrimental effect on your candidacy. Whether that potential impact is a worthwhile trade-off is a personal choice (off-topic). Whether a particular company or interviewer will object is a crapshoot (off-topic). Frankly speaking, if a candidate would let something as silly as this get in the way of making a good impression then that tells me plenty about his professional priorities. (Noticed @Meelah's comment as I posted mine, I basically agree with his point on immaturity.)

Comment: Also take a look at [Chad's answer](http://workplace.stackexchange.com/a/13221/16983) and [congusbongus's answer](http://workplace.stackexchange.com/a/13238/16983) in the linked question, which specifically address well-groomed vs. messy. This question is still a duplicate.

Comment: @DavidK Thank you for linking is answer, I only read the topic few and didn't see his which brought up some good points. Will edit answer.

Comment: The tidier the better for an interview, first impressions set the tone.

Comment: The time to start growing a beard is NOT during interview season. If you must do it, keep your neck clean-shaven and trim the uneven spots. No one likes a neck-beard, it is just uncool looking. Depending on your looks, you might be able get away with a bit of fashionable scruffiness, but if you have to ask, you probably can't and shouldn't do it.

Comment: Is this actually to raise awareness? Would you be willing to mention to a prospective employer that the reason for your appearance is to raise awareness, and that you don't normally look so "unkempt"?

Comment: This is one of those great examples where rejection works both ways. If they don't hire you because you don't shave for charity, then you avoid working for a company that considers it unprofessional to not shave for charity. If they had hired you, you'd have been working for them next November. So if this is something you want to do, then doing it is pretty smart. If it's not the kind of thing you really care about, then doing it and losing a job because of it is not so smart. If you expect not to do it once you have a job, may as well knock it on the head before interviews.