# Can I keep my beard while interviewing?

Tags: interviewing, employer-relations

As a Muslim it is [Sunnah](https://www.britannica.com/topic/Sunnah) to wear a beard.  I wear a beard for religious reasons, but I am worried that it might affect my interviews.  Should I tell the interviewer why I wear a beard?

Comment: I have a beard for no reason other than personal preference. I wouldn't shave it for an interview. If the interviewer doesn't like my beard and would make it a factor in his decision on hiring me I wouldn't want to work there.

Comment: What industry?  Where are you in the world?  Are there cultural conventions about beards (or their absence)?  Please [edit] in more details.  I'm putting this on hold temporarily so people don't spend energy on answers based on wrong guesses; once you edit it'll be reviewed for reopening.  Thanks.

Comment: See this very relevant question: [Are beards perceived as unprofessional in the workplace?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/13216/are-beards-perceived-as-unprofessional-in-the-workplace)

Comment: Killer066, is wearing a beard considered abnormal where you live and work (outside of the Muslim community)?  I can't speak for others, but I live in a place where beards wouldn't raise an eyebrow and certainly wouldn't require an explanation, which tells me that my context is not your context.  If you can add some details to the question we'll be better able to help you.  We want to help you; we don't want to guess wrong.  You can click on the [edit] link under the question.  Thanks.

Comment: @Kilisi, I'm not going to get to into a religious argument. These answers are sufficient in answering my question.

Comment: @Killer066 I wasn't trying to argue theology, I'm not qualified, just using logic. Hard to understand why my comments got deleted.

Comment: In the USA, they'll just think you're a hipster.

Comment: Where are you interviewing?  Is this in the US?

Comment: What sort of positions will you be interviewing for?  In your potential new role, will you be interfacing with customers?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I am sure local custom may have some bearing  on this, and you don't say where you are, but in the US -- and I imagine most Western countries -- a beard shouldn't matter in the least. Make sure it's clean and combed, and be yourself.

Comment: I would say it depends on length too. I know a person with a beard down nearly to his waist and while at work - or in a professional setting - he ties it in a way that doesn't look absurdly longer than the norm.

Answer (score 2):

In the US, much like dress codes, grooming standards vary wildly depending on the workplace. Try to check out the workplace however you can before the interview; you should do this anyway to see dress code standards if none are provided to you. Frankly, most employers don't particularly care about beards--in Colorado huge lumberjack beards seem to be the norm--but the more strict the dress code the more likely they are to care.

I would never mention it if you get an interview, but if it is a strict shop, extra time and effort may be in order when you are trimming or grooming your beard.